# Opengl sws_scale is not working (segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg, rendering, video-capture

I am working on an OpenGL video application where I want to render a video in full screen mode. I am trying to render the video with following code:

```
GLFWmonitor* monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitor);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RED_BITS, mode->redBits);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_GREEN_BITS, mode->greenBits);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_BLUE_BITS, mode->blueBits);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_REFRESH_RATE, mode->refreshRate);
```

However, it generates a segmentation fault when I try to scale a video frame.
I am using the `ffmpeg` and `sws` scales for color conversion.

```
sws_scaler_ctx = sws_getContext(width, height, av_codec_ctx->pix_fmt,
                                width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB0,
                                SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);

uint8_t* dest[4] = { frame_buffer, NULL, NULL, NULL };
int dest_linesize[4] = { width*4, 0, 0, 0 };
sws_scale(sws_scaler_ctx, av_frame->data, av_frame->linesize, 0, av_frame->height, dest, dest_linesize);
```

Do anyone know why this would cause a segmentation fault when trying to scale a video frame?

Comment: How do you allocate `frame_buffer`?

Comment: Hi, I defined frame buffer    `uint8_t* frame_buffer`. 

Which Is also initiated as 

`uint8_t* frame_buffer= new uint8_t[frame_width * frame_height * 4];`.

Comment: `assert(frame_width == width && frame_height == height)`?

Comment: @ybungalobill it generated error while i am scaling. when i am scaling video frame and try to convert that frame into defined height and width which is not working or converting that's why it generate this error. if it because of my graphic card ?

Comment: Your code scales on the CPU, so your graphics card is out of the game. I suspect that you want to scale your frame but your code is incorrect -- you pass same width and height to `sws_getContext` for both source and destination. Try fixing that?

Comment: @ybungalobill thanks for advice. solved it with scaling  ```sws_scale(data->conv_ctx, data->av_frame->data, data->av_frame->linesize, 0,
                          data->codec_ctx->height, data->gl_frame->data, data->gl_frame->linesize);```  fix the problem .

Answer (score 1):

```
 sws_scale(data->conv_ctx, data->av_frame->data, data->av_frame->linesize, 0,
                          data->codec_ctx->height, data->gl_frame->data, data->gl_frame->linesize);
```

it is scaleing windows monitor and fix my problem.